# A page to display various membership types to choose from?

Tags: users

I am completely newbie to Drupal, currently using Drupal 7.x

Though I am experience hard-core IT professional, I am trying to learn Drupal.

I have a simple requirement to display a page when user clicks on "Create new account".

The page should display three columns giving details of  three types of memberships, basic, premium and enterprise. Three memberships should be display in three columns and at the bottom of column there should be button "Register" which should take user to fill registration details.

Please could you guide me how to do that.

Regards
TD

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom module to do it exactly as you desire, and you probably won't find anyone here to do it for you, so you need to do more research if you go that approach.

A simpler approach does not require a custom module:

- create a block with the three "tables" as images (to be prettier in my opinion)
- add that block to the content-top of whichever theme you have
- restrict the content to only show on the user/register page
- under admin/config/people/accounts/fields add a new field of type list(text) that includes the three types of account, required at registration
- if desired - set a Rule to act on new account registration to take care of role changes or other account differences based on the value of the drop-down selection

This will show the three options at registration and require the user to choose one of them - the Rules will then act on that choice to change the account as desired

Comment: Thanks Geoff

I appreciate you replied such question.

I understand I have to go through a learning curve. I am already doing research and reading whatever I am getting, good thing about Drupal is a lot of information available on net.

However I am not sure what are the industry standards and what is the good approach.

I came across multi step registration module as well, but currently I am getting lost in small things like how to change user/register to point to my membership selection page etc.

Out of the two approaches you mentioned, do you think module approach is better?

TD

Comment: they will probably be functionally too similar to say one is better. The real difference is in appearance and how strictly you want to hold to the original plan. Another option would be to use my suggestion (or a multi-step form) short term, and continue to work on perfecting it long-term - at least then you have a working model within a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks, am I right in thinking that menu provides link between form/pages even if menus are not displayed. I mean what I understand from term Menu is they are displayed at page and provides a navigation path. but I have noticed in Drupal that they seems to be linking place and not necessarily displayed at page. Please correct me!

Comment: the word *menu* is used to describe the basic setup of the hierarchical page layout, as well as the more common menu that you see (or don't if its hidden). Its double meaning (though some would criticize me Im sure for saying this) is unnecessarily confusing in that regard.